# How to gsub escaped quotes

Tags: r, gsub

I have escaped quotes in my csv file which I am attempting to gsub out so that the files can be read in with fread. The following is an example of one of the lines in the data which needs to be fixed:

```
[1] "\"549300UIFHFOUTLOYP82\",\"\"Maritime Centre, United Kingdom\"\",\"\",\"N\""
```

The code I am using is:

```
data <- readLines(file)
data <- gsub('([^,])"([^,])', '', data)
```

This gets the following result:

```
[1] "\"549300UIFHFOUTLOYP82\",aritime Centre, United Kingdo,\"\",\"N\""
```

What I am looking for is:

```
[1] "\"549300UIFHFOUTLOYP82\",\"Maritime Centre, United Kingdom\",\"\",\"N\""
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong in this code?

Comment: which package is fread? Asking because read.table and its ilk will ignore the char specified under `quote` (which in your example will lead to "Maritime Centre, United Kingdom" being read as two variables). agh, nevermind, it's `data.table::fread`

Comment: fread is from data.table v1.9.7. The Sep has to be \",\"

Comment: i see. but `data.table::fread` will also ignore your quotes for you, i.e., will read "Maritime Centre, United Kingdom" as two variables.

Comment: so what i think you want to do is replace the double escaped quotes \"\" with maybe backticks, but i didnt check if that would work.

Comment: ...nope, replacing with backticks doesn't prevent that.

Comment: The objective is for fread to read  "Maritime Centre, United Kingdom" as one variable. So ultimatley there will be 4 columns (not 5).

Comment: How about `gsub("\"(\"[^\"]+\")\"", "\\1", data, perl = TRUE)` ?

Comment: It does actually fix it for this problem. Thanks. Though it causes problems in the rest of the dataset..

Answer (score 0):

replace double escaped quotes around values, but not for empty values:

```
yourString <- string <-  "\"549300UIFHFOUTLOYP82\",\"\"Maritime Centre, United Kingdom\"\",\"\",\"N\""
newString <- gsub("(\"\")(.+?)(\"\")","\"\\2\"", yourString, fixed=FALSE)
```

does this read "Maritime Centre, United Kingdom" correctly?

```
textCon <- textConnection(newString)
d <- read.csv(textCon)
str(d)

#'data.frame':  0 obs. of  4 variables:
#$ X549300UIFHFOUTLOYP82          : logi 
#$ Maritime.Centre..United.Kingdom: logi 
#$ X                              : logi 
#$ N                              : logi
```

it does :)